# How can my Qt5 app know programmatically what windows and dialogs are running?

Tags: c++, dialog, widget, window, qt5

I need to know programmatically what windows/dialogs/widgets are open, because I'm using `FileOpenEvent` to load a file, and I only want to load the file if my `QMainWindow` is the only thing open.

Answer (score 0):

I found that iterating through all `QWindow`s and checking for more than one with `isExposed() == true` handles everything I'm doing, except for native Mac dialogs (Save As, Print, and Open File).  So this seems sufficient for my needs:

```
  bool found_exposed_window = false;
  foreach (QWindow *window, qApp->allWindows()) {
    if (window->isExposed()) {
      if (found_exposed_window) {
        // This is the second exposed window, meaning the user has something
        //  open in addition to the main form.
        // So, don't try to load a file.
        return;
      }

      found_exposed_window = true;
    }
  }
```